# Interceptor for all calls in servicemix

Tags: interceptor, apache-servicemix

What is the best way to add an interceptor to servicemix that would log all webservice calls (or calls to osgi components would also work)?

I know of the NMR interceptors, but these apparently don't work for CXF.
And I know about "jaxws:inInterceptors" but these need to be added to each endpoint manually.

I would like to intercept the calls to all endpoints (WS and RS) with a single configuration/interceptor, is this possible in servicemix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can just add [CXF logging feature](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/features.html) like this

```
<!-- adding the feature to the bus-->
<cxf:bus>
    <cxf:features>
        <cxf:logging/>
    </cxf:features>
</cxf:bus>
```

Comment: Hey thanks, this was great info. Probably just what I needed. If I need to add a "global" custom feature (other than eg. logging) here was some more info http://cxf.apache.org/docs/bus-configuration.html